# Go to specific page in large list

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, navigation

I got a list that have about 200 items and growing. Is there a way to navigate to a specific page of that list? Something similar that are on forums all over. Or a dropdown?

We are using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Ivar

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Like in the Overview or the item display page?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the URL to that list you can normally just add /Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID= and then the ID number of the item you want to show.

Comment: The (non-technical) users will kill me if I tell them that is the only solution :)

Comment: Is there a way to link to DispForm.asps using Title or another field? e.g. `DispForm.aspx?title=Apple`

Answer (score 0):

You could create custom views that filter the items shown reducing the need for paging. You could also increase the Item Limit of the All Items view to increase the number of items shown per page.